# How to write a text in the pdf file using itext at a given position using java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Im using PdfTemplate.createTemplate with following code,

```
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Report.pdf"));     
 document.open();
 document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF new TEXT document."));
 PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();    
 PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(50,50);
 template.beginText();
 BaseFont bf=BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1252,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
 template.setFontAndSize(bf,10);
 template.setTextMatrix(100,100);    
 template.showText("Text at the position 100,100 (relative to the template!)");
 template.endText();
 contentByte.addTemplate(template, 10, 100);
 document.close();
```

But the text is not visible in the pdf

Comment: *But the text is not visible* - what do you expect? After all, you draw text in a 50x50 template at position 100,100...

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(50,50);
```

You create a canvas that measures 50 user units by 50 user units. All the content that you add to this canvas will be *clipped* to that size.

When you do this:

```
template.setTextMatrix(100,100);
```

You deliberately move outside the visible area of the small square with lower-left corner 0,0 and upper-right corner 50,50. Whatever you add in this area will be clipped.

You are correct when you say: *the text is not visible in the pdf.* If the text were visible, you would have found a bug.

Comment: Can you please share a example to write a text at specified position.Its still not working for me.

Comment: Download [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) for free and look at the examples in the chapter about adding content at absolute positions. You'll notice that your code is overly complex. You'll save plenty of time and you'll have less problems if you learn how to use iText from the official documentation before writing code.